# Traversing Table and extracting information from data using selenium Python3

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, selenium

The following is the code for the table:

```html
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="">
   <thead>
      <tr draggable="true" style="">
         <th id="symbol" class="sortable">
            <div class="container"><span class="content">Symbol</span><span class="order">&nbsp;</span></div>
            <div class="sizer"><span></span></div>
         </th>
         <th id="tiket" class="sortable">
            <div class="container"><span class="content">Ticket</span><span class="order">&nbsp;</span></div>
            <div class="sizer"><span></span></div>
         </th>
         <th id="open_time" class="sortable sort-down" style="text-align: right;">
            <div class="container"><span class="content">Time</span><span class="order">&nbsp;</span></div>
            <div class="sizer"><span></span></div>
         </th>
         <th id="type" class="sortable" style="text-align: right;">
            <div class="container"><span class="content">Type</span><span class="order">&nbsp;</span></div>
            <div class="sizer"><span></span></div>
         </th>
         <th id="volume" class="sortable" style="text-align: right;">
            <div class="container"><span class="content">Volume</span><span class="order">&nbsp;</span></div>
            <div class="sizer"><span></span></div>
         </th>
         <th id="open_price" class="sortable" style="text-align: right;">
            <div class="container"><span class="content">Price</span><span class="order">&nbsp;</span></div>
            <div class="sizer"><span></span></div>
         </th>
         <th id="sl" class="sortable" style="text-align: right;">
            <div class="container"><span class="content">S / L</span><span class="order">&nbsp;</span></div>
            <div class="sizer"><span></span></div>
         </th>
         <th id="tp" class="sortable" style="text-align: right;">
            <div class="container"><span class="content">T / P</span><span class="order">&nbsp;</span></div>
            <div class="sizer"><span></span></div>
         </th>
         <th id="close_price" class="sortable" style="text-align: right;">
            <div class="container"><span class="content">Price</span><span class="order">&nbsp;</span></div>
            <div class="sizer"><span></span></div>
         </th>
         <th id="swap" class="sortable" style="text-align: right;">
            <div class="container"><span class="content">Swap</span><span class="order">&nbsp;</span></div>
            <div class="sizer"><span></span></div>
         </th>
         <th id="profit" class="sortable" style="text-align: right;">
            <div class="container"><span class="content">Profit</span><span class="order">&nbsp;</span></div>
            <div class="sizer"><span></span></div>
         </th>
         <th id="comment" class="sortable last" style="text-align: right;">
            <div class="container"><span class="content">Comment</span><span class="order">&nbsp;</span></div>
            <div class="sizer"><span></span></div>
         </th>
         <th style="width: 0px;"></th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody style="">
      <tr id="position_168325043" class="filled" title="" draggable="true">
         <td id="symbol" class="iconed" title="US Dollar vs Japanese Yen">
            <div class="container"><span class="content"><span class="i sell">&nbsp;</span>usdjpy</span></div>
         </td>
         <td id="tiket" class="">
            <div class="container"><span class="content">168325043</span></div>
         </td>
         <td id="open_time" class="" style="text-align: right;">
            <div class="container"><span class="content">2021.11.12 21:35:52</span></div>
         </td>
         <td id="type" class="" style="text-align: right;">
            <div class="container"><span class="content">sell</span></div>
         </td>
         <td id="volume" class="" style="text-align: right;">
            <div class="container"><span class="content">0.01</span></div>
         </td>
         <td id="open_price" class="" style="text-align: right;">
            <div class="container"><span class="content">113.926</span></div>
         </td>
         <td id="sl" class="" style="text-align: right;">
            <div class="container"><span class="content">0.000</span></div>
         </td>
         <td id="tp" class="" style="text-align: right;">
            <div class="container"><span class="content">0.000</span></div>
         </td>
         <td id="close_price" class="" style="text-align: right;">
            <div class="container"><span class="content">113.928</span></div>
         </td>
         <td id="swap" class="" style="text-align: right;">
            <div class="container"><span class="content">0.00</span></div>
         </td>
         <td id="profit" class="" style="text-align: right;">
            <div class="container"><span class="content">-0.02<span title="Close #168325043 sell 0.01 USDJPY 113.926" class="close"><span class="x"></span></span></span></div>
         </td>
         <td id="comment" class="" style="text-align: right;">
            <div class="container"><span class="content"></span></div>
         </td>
         <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="position_168325045" class="filled" title="" draggable="true">
         <td id="symbol" class="iconed" title="Euro vs US Dollar">
            <div class="container"><span class="content"><span class="i sell">&nbsp;</span>eurusd</span></div>
         </td>
         <td id="tiket" class="">
            <div class="container"><span class="content">168325045</span></div>
         </td>
         <td id="open_time" class="" style="text-align: right;">
            <div class="container"><span class="content">2021.11.12 21:35:55</span></div>
         </td>
         <td id="type" class="" style="text-align: right;">
            <div class="container"><span class="content">sell</span></div>
         </td>
         <td id="volume" class="" style="text-align: right;">
            <div class="container"><span class="content">0.01</span></div>
         </td>
         <td id="open_price" class="" style="text-align: right;">
            <div class="container"><span class="content">1.14434</span></div>
         </td>
         <td id="sl" class="" style="text-align: right;">
            <div class="container"><span class="content">0.00000</span></div>
         </td>
         <td id="tp" class="" style="text-align: right;">
            <div class="container"><span class="content">0.00000</span></div>
         </td>
         <td id="close_price" class="" style="text-align: right;">
            <div class="container"><span class="content">1.14440</span></div>
         </td>
         <td id="swap" class="" style="text-align: right;">
            <div class="container"><span class="content">0.00</span></div>
         </td>
         <td id="profit" class="" style="text-align: right;">
            <div class="container"><span class="content">-0.06<span title="Close #168325045 sell 0.01 EURUSD 1.14434" class="close"><span class="x"></span></span></span></div>
         </td>
         <td id="comment" class="" style="text-align: right;">
            <div class="container"><span class="content"></span></div>
         </td>
         <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="position_168325047" class="filled" title="" draggable="true">
         <td id="symbol" class="iconed" title="Euro vs US Dollar">
            <div class="container"><span class="content"><span class="i buy">&nbsp;</span>eurusd</span></div>
         </td>
         <td id="tiket" class="">
            <div class="container"><span class="content">168325047</span></div>
         </td>
         <td id="open_time" class="" style="text-align: right;">
            <div class="container"><span class="content">2021.11.12 21:35:57</span></div>
         </td>
         <td id="type" class="" style="text-align: right;">
            <div class="container"><span class="content">buy</span></div>
         </td>
         <td id="volume" class="" style="text-align: right;">
            <div class="container"><span class="content">0.01</span></div>
         </td>
         <td id="open_price" class="" style="text-align: right;">
            <div class="container"><span class="content">1.14438</span></div>
         </td>
         <td id="sl" class="" style="text-align: right;">
            <div class="container"><span class="content">0.00000</span></div>
         </td>
         <td id="tp" class="" style="text-align: right;">
            <div class="container"><span class="content">0.00000</span></div>
         </td>
         <td id="close_price" class="" style="text-align: right;">
            <div class="container"><span class="content">1.14440</span></div>
         </td>
         <td id="swap" class="" style="text-align: right;">
            <div class="container"><span class="content">0.00</span></div>
         </td>
         <td id="profit" class="" style="text-align: right;">
            <div class="container"><span class="content">0.02<span title="Close #168325047 buy 0.01 EURUSD 1.14438" class="close"><span class="x"></span></span></span></div>
         </td>
         <td id="comment" class="" style="text-align: right;">
            <div class="container"><span class="content"></span></div>
         </td>
         <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="position_168325081" class="filled" title="" draggable="true">
         <td id="symbol" class="iconed" title="Great Britain Pound vs US Dollar">
            <div class="container"><span class="content"><span class="i sell">&nbsp;</span>gbpusd</span></div>
         </td>
         <td id="tiket" class="">
            <div class="container"><span class="content">168325081</span></div>
         </td>
         <td id="open_time" class="" style="text-align: right;">
            <div class="container"><span class="content">2021.11.12 21:36:04</span></div>
         </td>
         <td id="type" class="" style="text-align: right;">
            <div class="container"><span class="content">sell</span></div>
         </td>
         <td id="volume" class="" style="text-align: right;">
            <div class="container"><span class="content">0.01</span></div>
         </td>
         <td id="open_price" class="" style="text-align: right;">
            <div class="container"><span class="content">1.34213</span></div>
         </td>
         <td id="sl" class="" style="text-align: right;">
            <div class="container"><span class="content">0.00000</span></div>
         </td>
         <td id="tp" class="" style="text-align: right;">
            <div class="container"><span class="content">0.00000</span></div>
         </td>
         <td id="close_price" class="" style="text-align: right;">
            <div class="container"><span class="content">1.34184</span></div>
         </td>
         <td id="swap" class="" style="text-align: right;">
            <div class="container"><span class="content">0.00</span></div>
         </td>
         <td id="profit" class="" style="text-align: right;">
            <div class="container"><span class="content">0.29<span title="Close #168325081 sell 0.01 GBPUSD 1.34213" class="close"><span class="x"></span></span></span></div>
         </td>
         <td id="comment" class="" style="text-align: right;">
            <div class="container"><span class="content"></span></div>
         </td>
         <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="position_168325084" class="filled" title="" draggable="true">
         <td id="symbol" class="iconed" title="Great Britain Pound vs US Dollar">
            <div class="container"><span class="content"><span class="i buy">&nbsp;</span>gbpusd</span></div>
         </td>
         <td id="tiket" class="">
            <div class="container"><span class="content">168325084</span></div>
         </td>
         <td id="open_time" class="" style="text-align: right;">
            <div class="container"><span class="content">2021.11.12 21:36:05</span></div>
         </td>
         <td id="type" class="" style="text-align: right;">
            <div class="container"><span class="content">buy</span></div>
         </td>
         <td id="volume" class="" style="text-align: right;">
            <div class="container"><span class="content">0.01</span></div>
         </td>
         <td id="open_price" class="" style="text-align: right;">
            <div class="container"><span class="content">1.34215</span></div>
         </td>
         <td id="sl" class="" style="text-align: right;">
            <div class="container"><span class="content">0.00000</span></div>
         </td>
         <td id="tp" class="" style="text-align: right;">
            <div class="container"><span class="content">0.00000</span></div>
         </td>
         <td id="close_price" class="" style="text-align: right;">
            <div class="container"><span class="content">1.34181</span></div>
         </td>
         <td id="swap" class="" style="text-align: right;">
            <div class="container"><span class="content">0.00</span></div>
         </td>
         <td id="profit" class="" style="text-align: right;">
            <div class="container"><span class="content">-0.34<span title="Close #168325084 buy 0.01 GBPUSD 1.34215" class="close"><span class="x"></span></span></span></div>
         </td>
         <td id="comment" class="" style="text-align: right;">
            <div class="container"><span class="content"></span></div>
         </td>
         <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="position_168325136" class="filled" title="" draggable="true">
         <td id="symbol" class="iconed" title="Great Britain Pound vs US Dollar">
            <div class="container"><span class="content"><span class="i sell">&nbsp;</span>gbpusd</span></div>
         </td>
         <td id="tiket" class="">
            <div class="container"><span class="content">168325136</span></div>
         </td>
         <td id="open_time" class="" style="text-align: right;">
            <div class="container"><span class="content">2021.11.12 21:36:40</span></div>
         </td>
         <td id="type" class="" style="text-align: right;">
            <div class="container"><span class="content">sell</span></div>
         </td>
         <td id="volume" class="" style="text-align: right;">
            <div class="container"><span class="content">0.01</span></div>
         </td>
         <td id="open_price" class="" style="text-align: right;">
            <div class="container"><span class="content">1.34218</span></div>
         </td>
         <td id="sl" class="" style="text-align: right;">
            <div class="container"><span class="content">0.00000</span></div>
         </td>
         <td id="tp" class="" style="text-align: right;">
            <div class="container"><span class="content">0.00000</span></div>
         </td>
         <td id="close_price" class="" style="text-align: right;">
            <div class="container"><span class="content">1.34184</span></div>
         </td>
         <td id="swap" class="" style="text-align: right;">
            <div class="container"><span class="content">0.00</span></div>
         </td>
         <td id="profit" class="" style="text-align: right;">
            <div class="container"><span class="content">0.34<span title="Close #168325136 sell 0.01 GBPUSD 1.34218" class="close"><span class="x"></span></span></span></div>
         </td>
         <td id="comment" class="" style="text-align: right;">
            <div class="container"><span class="content"></span></div>
         </td>
         <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="position_168325151" class="filled" title="" draggable="true">
         <td id="symbol" class="iconed" title="Euro vs US Dollar">
            <div class="container"><span class="content"><span class="i buy">&nbsp;</span>eurusd</span></div>
         </td>
         <td id="tiket" class="">
            <div class="container"><span class="content">168325151</span></div>
         </td>
         <td id="open_time" class="" style="text-align: right;">
            <div class="container"><span class="content">2021.11.12 21:36:55</span></div>
         </td>
         <td id="type" class="" style="text-align: right;">
            <div class="container"><span class="content">buy</span></div>
         </td>
         <td id="volume" class="" style="text-align: right;">
            <div class="container"><span class="content">0.01</span></div>
         </td>
         <td id="open_price" class="" style="text-align: right;">
            <div class="container"><span class="content">1.14430</span></div>
         </td>
         <td id="sl" class="" style="text-align: right;">
            <div class="container"><span class="content">0.00000</span></div>
         </td>
         <td id="tp" class="" style="text-align: right;">
            <div class="container"><span class="content">0.00000</span></div>
         </td>
         <td id="close_price" class="" style="text-align: right;">
            <div class="container"><span class="content">1.14440</span></div>
         </td>
         <td id="swap" class="" style="text-align: right;">
            <div class="container"><span class="content">0.00</span></div>
         </td>
         <td id="profit" class="" style="text-align: right;">
            <div class="container"><span class="content">0.10<span title="Close #168325151 buy 0.01 EURUSD 1.14430" class="close"><span class="x"></span></span></span></div>
         </td>
         <td id="comment" class="" style="text-align: right;">
            <div class="container"><span class="content"></span></div>
         </td>
         <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="total" class="total filled" title="" draggable="false">
         <td id="symbol" class="iconed" colspan="10">
            <div class="container"><span class="content"><span class="i equity_up">&nbsp;</span>Balance: 4&nbsp;999&nbsp;337.42 USD&nbsp;&nbsp;Equity: 4&nbsp;999&nbsp;337.76&nbsp;&nbsp;Margin: 4.97&nbsp;&nbsp;Free margin: 4&nbsp;999&nbsp;332.79&nbsp;&nbsp;Margin level: 100&nbsp;590&nbsp;296.98 %</span></div>
         </td>
         <td id="profit" class="profit" style="text-align: right;">
            <div class="container"><span class="content">0.34</span></div>
         </td>
         <td id="comment" class="" style="text-align: right;">
            <div class="container"><span class="content"></span></div>
         </td>
         <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="" class="empty" title="" draggable="false">
         <td id="symbol" class="iconed" colspan="10">
            <div class="container"><span class="content"><span class="i equity_down">&nbsp;</span>Balance: 4&nbsp;999&nbsp;337.42 USD&nbsp;&nbsp;Equity: 4&nbsp;999&nbsp;337.33&nbsp;&nbsp;Margin: 4.97&nbsp;&nbsp;Free margin: 4&nbsp;999&nbsp;332.36&nbsp;&nbsp;Margin level: 100&nbsp;590&nbsp;288.33 %</span></div>
         </td>
         <td id="profit" class="profit" style="text-align: right;">
            <div class="container"><span class="content">-0.09</span></div>
         </td>
         <td id="comment" class="" style="text-align: right;">
            <div class="container"><span class="content"></span></div>
         </td>
         <td></td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

This is how I am trying to traverse and check the value to extract:

```
table = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[6]/div[1]/div[1]/table")
for row in table.find_elements_by_xpath(".//tr"):
     print([td.text for td in row.find_elements_by_xpath(".//td[@class='filled']")])
```

Always getting the following output with now error:

```
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
```

Let me know how to extract and gather information about the Symbol and ticket column of the table this. I think I am doing something wrong but I do not know what.

Comment: What output did you what? All the values in the tbody with tr class filled? Cause currently you are looking for td class filled. td instead of tr has no values.

Comment: Move the @class='filled'] up one line for the trs instead of the td cause it's not the right tag.

Comment: @ArundeepChohan I have printed the td values and I am getting the data, but what if I want the row as complete like list. Current I was able to crawl the data without issues but value from each column in a row. Please can you advise?